# Custom build script in react to publish the custom files

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-scripts

I have a custom build script written to build my react application.

```
 const rewire = require('rewire')
const defaults = rewire('react-scripts/scripts/build.js')
const config = defaults.__get__('config')

config.optimization.splitChunks = {
  cacheGroups: {
    default: false
  }
}
config.optimization.runtimeChunk = false
config.output.filename = 'static/js/product3.js'
config.plugins[5].options.moduleFilename = () => 'static/css/product3.css'
config.output.libraryTarget = 'umd'
config.externals = {
  react: {
    root: 'React',
    commonjs2: 'react',
    commonjs: 'react',
    amd: 'react'
  },
  'react-dom': {
    root: 'ReactDOM',
    commonjs2: 'react-dom',
    commonjs: 'react-dom',
    amd: 'react-dom'
  }
}
```

This creates a build . However my project also includes a config/env.json file which i need to package in the build.
Is there any way I could tweak the above build file so that the build  includes the config/env.json?

Comment: You mean js code of application depends on `node_env` variable? and you want to include `node_env` object in build?

Comment: No, the env file has constants related to our project. I simply need to copy the json file into generated build folder. Is there any way to do it via build. Js